# Why do keys() and items() methods return different Boolean values for same key? (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, dictionary, key, items

```
>>> spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}
>>> 'name' in spam.keys()
True
>>> 'name' in spam.items()
False
>>>
```

In python 3.6, when checking whether a key exists in a dictionary the `keys()` method returns `True`, while the `items()` method returns `False` for the same key. Why is that the case?

Comment: `items()` returns items (keys and values in pairs of tuples). You can print the result of the `items()` method to see the content by yourself.

Comment: Did you see the output difference in `spam.keys()` and `spam.items()`

Comment: just use `'name' in spam` BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items()` contains **tuples**, key-value pairs:

```
>>> spam.items()
dict_items([('name', 'Zophie'), ('age', 7)])
```

Your key is not such a tuple. It may be *contained* in one of the tuples, but `in` does not test for containment recursively.

Either test for the correct key-value tuple:

```
>>> ('name', 'Zophie') in spam.items()
True
```

or if you can't get access to just the `keys()` dictionary view, use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test each pair individually (iteration is halted early when a match is found):

```
>>> any('name' in pair for pair in spam.items())
True
```

or

```
>>> any(key == 'name' for key, value in spam.items())
True
```

On a separate note, if all you are doing is testing for a key, then just use `key in dictionary`. There is *no need* to create a separate dictionary view over the keys for that case; it's just a waste of Python cycles and memory as containment testing against the dictionary achieves the exact same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is because items() returns a list of key and value pairs.

```
>>> spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}
>>> spam.keys()
dict_keys(['name', 'age'])
>>> spam.items()
dict_items([('name', 'Zophie'), ('age', 7)])
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3, not Python 2, and the calls return *dictionary views*. That doesn't matter that much to the technical merits of your answer, but the output looks somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.keys()` will return a list but `dict.items()` will return you list of tuples in `key,value` pair so it would not match.

for example :

`name is not equal to ('name': 'Zophie')`

Hope you get the point.

Comment: Neither of these methods return a `list` in Python 3, rather, they return a view.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are different.

In your spam variable --> `spam = {'name': 'Zophie', 'age': 7}`:

`name`, and `age` are the **Keys**.
`'name': 'Zophie'` and `'age': 7`, the **items**.